# Android Download image after login with HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I want to download image from remote url.

I should authenticated with posting `unamw=asdasd&pass=qwerty` in `login.aspx` then
I have to download image from `image.aspx?id=2121212`

How can I do this?

I search about it but I cant find any solution.

Comment: I solved it. I is easy. 
First create login with httpclient and then download with same httpclient.